# Get fragment from NavController

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, navigation

I have one NavController (navOrdersController) with 2 fragments inside. My current fragment is OrderDetailFragment and I want access to first Fragment (OrdersFragment) to update data in MainActivity. How can I do this?

[image]

I tried findFragmentByTag and findFragmentByID but always return null.

I got access OrderDetailFragment with:

```
this.supportFragmentManager.fragments[position].findNavController().currentDestination
```

[image]

But I need previous fragment. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Can't say the code snippet (I've added below) is the best solution, but it worked for me to get the recent/current fragment added in `NavHostFragment` used in Android Navigation Component's implementations

OR

You can even override `onActivityResult` of the you activity with your fragment's, all you need is to get the added `Fragment` and call it's `onActivityResult`, using this code snippet:

```
    NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    Fragment fragment = navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If both the fragments have same parent activity, i.e. use `getActivity()` to get activity reference and use Activity.getSupportFragmentManager to find the fragment.

.....

Activity X -> Fragment A -> Fragment B

If fragment B is child of Fragment A, use getParentFragment. The fragment you are looking for would be this fragment.

Let me know if anything is not clear.

PS: Jetpack Navigation library does the same thing which we have been doing explicit. So, the previous logic of Activity-Fragment is still valid.

EDIT:

try out `(parentFragment as NavHostFragment).childFragmentManager.findFragmentById()`

I forgot last time that activity has declaration of NavHostFragment in its layout so there will always root parent fragment of type 'NavHostFrament'

EDIT:
I have found a work around for it

```
parentFragment.childFragmentManager.getFragment(Bundle().also { it.putInt("foobar",0) }, "foobar")
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. It doesn't work because parent is an NavGraph, and child is OrderDetailFragment. OrdersFragment is in the middle

Comment: NavGraph should not be a parent. Because the parent can be `Activity` or `Fragment`. I am not sure though. Give me a few minutes to check.

Comment: It doesn´t work. "null cannot be cast to non-null type android.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment" because parent is null. I updated my question. I have to work with navController

Comment: here zero is the backstack index (which should have been in case you were implementing the graph yourself)

Comment: Thanks Rahul but still not working, parent is null. Fragments are inside NavController